# Make a custom lemmatizer dictionary from txt file

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, utf-8, nlp, lemmatization

So I have the following txt file (lem_es.txt):

1 primer
1 primera
1 primeras
1 primero
1 primeros
(...) 
comer coma
comer comais

The txt file starts with some numbers but then goes on with all the verb conjugations.

I am trying to make a lemmatizer dictionary. I would like the words from the second column as the dictionary key, and the words/numbers from the first column as the dictionary values.

I am having some problems because the formula I am trying to use only takes unique values, so the number 1 only appears once and it disorder all.

The output I need:

{'primer': '1', 'primera': '1', 'primeras': '1', 'primero':' 1', 'primeros': '1', 'coma': 'comer', 'comais': 'comer...}

And this is what I am trying to do with the Output I received:

```
python

dict = {}
with codecs.open("lem_es.txt", "r", "utf-8-sig") as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle.readlines():
        dict[line.split()[-1]] = line.split()[0]

#Output:
{'primer': '1',
 'primera': 'primero',
 'primeras': 'primero',
 'primero': '1',
 'primeros': 'primero'...
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Other than being a bit inefficient iterating twice (just use `for line in filehandle:`) and splitting the line twice, the output appears to be what you want.  What do you mean by "the so the number 1 only appears once and it disorder all"?  What is your desired output? Also, `codecs.open` isn't needed.  The built-in `open` of Python 3 takes an encoding parameter.

Comment: Your list probably has `primero primera` further down, which overwrites the former entry `'primera': '1'` with `'primera': 'primero'`. You'll run into the same problem with ambiguous words like "como" which should be lemmatised to "comer" if it's a verb but to "como" if it's an adverb. This is why real-world lemmatisers are more than just dictionary look-up, but instead look at words in their context or require part-of-speech tags as additional input.